# Is it possible to change android background black colour?

Tags: android, colors, background, default

Is it possible to change the colour of background while switching between activities?
I mean the black colour what apear while one of activities disappear and before second appear. Thanks.

Comment: How are you switching Activities? This doesn't sound like typical Android behavior.

Comment: This is default switching, I don't put any animations, no overridePendingTransition. Just wonder if I can change black colour?

Answer (score 1):

Just you need to head over to the **activity_home.xml** 
At the starting lines of code add this background parameter to set the screen black

```
android:background="#ffffff"
```

Answer (score 0):

you may change the theme that you are using as follows:

```
application android:icon="@drawable/icon" android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Light" >
```

***Edit***
as mentioned in the documentation:

```
<application android:theme="@style/CustomTheme">
```

and then tweak the theme that you like:

```
<style>
<color name="custom_theme_color">#b0b0ff</color>
<style name="CustomTheme" parent="android:Theme.Light">
<item name="android:windowBackground">@color/custom_theme_color</item>
<item name="android:colorBackground">@color/custom_theme_color</item>
</style>
```

here is the link to the topic http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/themes.html#ApplyATheme

Comment: and for custom one? I need gray background between activities?